# Communication Link Failure (MYSQL SERVER 8 + JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql

THIS IS THE ERROR:

No Databasecom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,325 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,316 milliseconds ago.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connection Success");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
    }

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/" + str + "?useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true";
    try {
        DBConnection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "coderofGod24");
        System.out.println("Database Connected");
    } catch (SQLException xe) {
        System.out.println("No Database" + xe);
    }
    return DBConnection;
```

Comment: You seem to force SSL for the connection to localhost. Usually that is hard to get working. What is the output of this program. In case of failure it should output the messager of the exception from the third last line.

Comment: everything works fine until i change mysql server to 8. i used 5.7 before

Comment: Did you install the key and certificate also in the version 8? Did you upgrade the server?

Comment: theres no need for a key or certificate since community server is free. its up to date i believe.

Comment: you are using SSL ("useSSL=true"). SSL secures the TCP connection between client and server. SSL mandates a x509 certificate. It has nothing to do with licensing.

Comment: i placed that code because sql gives a long ass message warning regarding the certificate etc.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: need a specific version of mysql server. as for me, i need mysql community installer 5.7.21